# Problemas con un menu (navbar) en bootstap

Tags: css, bootstrap, menú

Estoy creando un navbar en bootstrap. Este es mi navbar:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <!-- Optional theme -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></head>

    <body>
      <style>
         #brand-image
         {
         height: 30px;
         }
      </style>
      <!-- Fixed navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.marca.com">
                  <img id="brand-image" alt="Website Logo" src="free.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">hola</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Static top</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Fixed top <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
         </div>
      </nav>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="container">
         <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
         <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1>Navbar example</h1>
            <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the default, static and fixed to top navbar work. It includes the responsive CSS and HTML, so it also adapts to your viewport and device.</p>
            <p>To see the difference between static and fixed top navbars, just scroll.</p>
            <p>
               <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /container -->
      <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
         ================================================== -->
      <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
      <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
      <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
     </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Pero me han salido unos problemas, que son estos y no soy capaz de solucionar. Necesito

1. **Reducir la distancia entre el "free" y el Home**

   [image]
2. **El Dropdown no funciona :/**
3. **Cuando pongo un icono delante de la una sección del navbar, se cambia el formato.¿Cómo puedo evitarlo?**

[image]

4. **Como se podría poner un Active background y Active color como esto:?**:

[image]

Intenté poner un padding a la derecha de la imagen pero no conseguí nada para reducir la distancia.
Para evitar el cambio de estilo, intenté poner un botón y lo del dropdown ni idea.

A ver si me podeis ayudar. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Que tal lo que deberias hacer respecto al punto numero 1 es agregarle un margin left en -10px o lo que le quieras poner  al texto... ya que el padding funciona para interior y no para exterior.

2. debes checar que tengas jquery gasta abajjo tanto el de bootstrap como el de jquery. sino no funciona
3. Se cambia al formato por que lo tienes dentro de la etiqueta del texto. No digo que no funcione pero puedes intentar ponerle un style distinto directo desde css.
4. debes ponerle la clase active a uno de la lista  o sea `<li class="active">`

Comment: Sobre el punto 1, he mirado todas las combinaciones de padding y margin y no funciona. En el punto 2 lo tengo exactamente igual y tampoco funciona. Los puntos 2 y 3 los miraré

Comment: <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://www.marca.com">
              <img id="brand-image" alt="Website Logo" src="free.png" />

Estoy viendo que te hace falta cerrar la etiqueta a

Comment: Vale, el punto nº2 me faltaba el css de bootstrap. Gracias. Tu comentario anterior no lo entiendo xd

Comment: Vale si, me faltaba cerrar la etiqueta.Gracias.  Sobre el punto 3, como lo harias?

Comment: con css le añades un estilo diferente al que ya tiene por ejemplo  
.navbar li a span {
      color: blue;
}

Answer (score 1):

Primero: No cerraste el anchor `<a></a>` 
Segundo: "hola" debe ir afuera del `<span class="glyphicon"></span>` 
Tercero: Revisa si el src de tus librerias son correctas 

Visita http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#template 
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar-default